# Java EE 7: EJB life cycle management with or without CDI? What are the differences?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I'm really confused about this. The Enterprise Javabeans has a system for managing lifecycle of beans, these are the `@Stateful`, `@Stateless` and `@Singleton`, so it's obviously managing lifecycles. However, the CDI also has another system that mirrors this, with `@Dependent`, `@RequestScoped`, `@SessionScoped` and `@Application` which looks to be the equivalent of `@Singleton` in EJB.

EJB's have to choose to use one system or the other if I understand correctly? But using the CDI gives finer grain control, for example the EJB system does not recognize requests versus sessions, which CDI does? Is this correct ?

Also some books state that CDI has context, while EJB lifecycle management doesn't, and resources need to be closed manually. I don't understand what they mean by this, as the EJB container is also managing the lifecycles of beans, so what is this "context" that CDI provides that EJB doesn't?

Thanks

Comment: There are too many questions in this single questions

Comment: You have already answered your question. The context of CDI beans is either the request, the session or the application. Just like it's with the faces managed beans. But faces managed beans have limited functionality in comparison to CDI beans. Standard EJBs don't have such a context at all.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of CDI and Session Beans (@Singleton is also a Session Bean) are a bit different:
Session Beans give you transaction management and concurrency, while CDI does not. 
You can of course write a producer for each Session Bean and have them injected with CDI in your application.

Answer (score 0):

CDI provides additional features on top of EJBs. They provide 'contextual' life cycle management of EJB (session beans). Being 'Contextual' means allowing the container to create and destroy instances and make them available to other beans executing in the same context. You define context of a bean by using scope related annotations like @RequestScoped etc. I wrote a [small blog post](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/valid-cdi-scoped-for-session-ejb-beans/) about this (might help). I would highly recommend reading [CDI specification document](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr346/index.html) - sections 1.2.2, 3.2, 7.3.2, 7.3.3